# Jones Polynomial and Quantum Field Theory

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, qa.quantum-algebra, sg.symplectic-geometry

I am trying Witten's paper but unable to re-produce the computations presented in the paper.
I tried few things on internet but all these tutorials explicitly don't show the calculations and refer to Witten's paper again for detailed calculations. Any suggestions if there is some material I can look at?

Comment: Witten's paper doesn't contain any detailed calculations either. And a number of things in that paper were only proved later by Taubes and others.

Comment: Hey David, thank you. So what do you suggest to understand this.